# Gmail API Message Payload.Data Comes Empty

Tags: c#, google-api, gmail-api

I'm trying to read the messages from the Google API but when I check the Payload.Body.Data to see the content of the email always comes null.
But when I use Raw format I see the body but it's a little complicated to handle the information because it's in a huge and dirty string.

```
public static Message GetMessage(GmailService service, String userId, String messageId)
{
    try
    {
        var request = service.Users.Messages.Get(userId, messageId);
        request.Format = Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest.FormatEnum.Full;
        var message = request.Execute();
        return message;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: If the body is a string than it is probably a Base 64 string.

Comment: It is, but where can I see the body then?

Comment: Depends on the type of data.  It could be a readable string, a word document, an image.

Comment: I tested "Try this API" on [Gmail > API > Users.messages > get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) to see the output. I can find payload.body with format > full, but when I put a format > raw and decode the raw contents I couldn't find any payload.body; May I ask you what you are trying to achieve? So maybe there are different ways.